# Checked on radio buttons is only working once

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am doing the following radio button code in a wordpress post loop:

```
<input id="<?php the_title(); ?>" type="radio" name="phoneSelect" value="test">
                 <label for="<?php the_title(); ?>">Select</label>
```

Each generated radio button has a unique id which assigns also a unique label for="". When I do the following styling, the checked element is only working on one radio button. When I select another radio button, the first button changes the style but the next radio button does not apply the css settings

```
input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
  }

  input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  }

  input[type=radio]:checked + label {
       background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
      background-color:#e0e0e0;
  }
```

The following JSfiddle can replicate the issue (obviously because the php isn't being executed) http://jsfiddle.net/83uc5xy5/

Comment: it works for me... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/cgd4t188/).

Comment: @leftside when I set manually different id's for each one it works fine. The id's are being injected with the_title(); of wordpress and should still be unique

Comment: ID's shouldn't matter. Check the jsFiddle again - no ID's now.

Comment: @leftside, ok so what I discovered is the following code is what causing the problem: `input[type=radio] {
    visibility:none; 
}`

Comment: @leftside You can check this fiddle replicating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/jeqy9s4m/

Comment: I thought you had this working now?

Comment: @leftside it works when the radio button is not set to hidden, I want to hide the radio button and only show the styling on the label

Comment: that would be handy to put in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example:

```
<div><input type="radio" name ="test" id="test"/>
    dasdas
</div>
<input type="radio" name ="test" id="test"/>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked{
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

It moves the selected checkbox with 50px from the top.

Comment: when I set manually different id's for each one it works fine. The id's are being injected with the_title(); of wordpress and should still be unique

Comment: This is not using ids anywhere it applies the style to input of type radio.